# Is a matrix with normalized columns and determinant $1$ an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, orthogonality

<strike>This is probably an elementary question.</strike>

Suppose that the column vectors of a matrix (in $\mathbb R^{d\times d}$) are all unit vectors. That implies that its determinant is bounded in absolute value by one.

If the determinant of that matrix is one, is the matrix orthogonal (and therefore all column vectors are in fact orthogonal to each other)?

To cross t's and dot i's : the norm is the Euclidean norm, and the scalar product is the usual scalar product in $\mathbb R^d$.

Because of the volume interpretation of the determinant, the answer should be yes. But what is a simple proof?

Comment: Couldn't this be rephrased as follows?  If a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix has $1$'s on its main diagonal and its determinant is $1$, then it is the identity matrix.

Comment: The answer is affirmative. Perform a QR factorisation to see that.

Comment: @user1551 : thank you, yes QR by Gram-Schmidt works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it follows from the so called Hadamard's inequality.
To put it simple, determinant is equal to volume of the cube spanned by columns.
Since in your case columns are normalized and volume is 1 they must be orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I compleltely agree with the geometric picture (which I mention in my post), but I wanted a direct proof. @user1551 suggested one, using Gram-Schmidt QR.

Comment: As I said - Hadamards inequality is a technical proof. No need to repeat it here.